# Javascript [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, html

Using Javascript I am creating a list website (as a side-project).

I use the code:

```
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
```

and that works, but

```
localStorage.setItem("myNodelist", document.getElementsByTagName("LI"));
```

doesn't. it just returns `[object HTMLCollection]`. Does anyone know why?

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      min-width: 250px;
    }
    /* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Remove margins and padding from the list */
    
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /* Style the list items */
    
    ul li {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
      list-style-type: none;
      background: #eee;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.2s;
      /* make the list items unselectable */
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    /* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
    
    ul li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    /* Darker background-color on hover */
    
    ul li:hover {
      background: #ddd;
    }
    /* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
    
    ul li.checked {
      background: #888;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }
    /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
    
    ul li.checked::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-color: #fff;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
      top: 10px;
      left: 16px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      height: 15px;
      width: 7px;
    }
    /* Style the close button */
    
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
    }
    
    .close:hover {
      background-color: #168e00;
      color: white;
    }
    /* Style the header */
    
    .header {
      background-color: #168e00;
      padding: 30px 40px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Clear floats after the header */
    
    .header:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    /* Style the input */
    
    input {
      margin: 0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      width: 75%;
      padding: 10px;
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    /* Style the "Add" button */
    
    .addBtn {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 25%;
      background: #d9d9d9;
      color: #555;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    
    .addBtn:hover {
      background-color: #bbb;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2 style="margin:5px">Groceries:</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
  </div>

  <ul id="myUL">

  </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You can only save strings in local storage. What does it mean to save DOM elements?

Comment: local storage can only store strings, so, document.getElementsByTagName gets converted to it's string representation, which happens to be `[object HTMLCollection]`

Comment: its storing a list. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If these are input fields, you need to loop over them and collect their values with `.value`. You can then convert the array of values to a string with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @FredTheDoggy A list of what? `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of DOM elements.

Comment: I updated the question with the code, does that help?

Comment: @FredTheDoggy: What is the *data* that you want to store?  "A list" could mean anything.  You need to understand and define what information you want to store, then you can structure and store it.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` is like a building in which the apartments containing the labels of your list are located. you must learn a little more about the architecture of the Dom before continuing on your naive vision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `var Lists = document.getElementsByTagName("List");` in your `console.log(list)` you will see the list of elements that you need right ?

The console.log also shows array the same way ,each element of an array is print to the log without you having to write a `for()` loop.

However if you want to use the array you have to write the **for loop**

> [object HTMLCollection]

means that there is an array of HTML objects, To work with the data  you have to use a for loop or array methods so before storing it in local storage

Try Make an array with the object collection with

```
var arr = Array.from(htmlCollection);
```

Then save as is or convert to json string with

```
 var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

I trust this helps

Answer (score 1):

First: its better if you use id to find the dom element from DOM API. 
 Second: you need to use `.innerText` to access the text content of list item.

```
<ul>
  <li id="item">hello</li>
</ul>

localStorage.setItem("myNodelist",document.getElementById("item").innerText);
```